# Why this vectorization fails on AVX-512 and not on AVX2?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, vectorization, avx2, avx512

I have this code which I test on my AVX2 machine:

```
bool interpolate(const Mat &im, float ofsx, float ofsy, float a11, float a12, float a21, float a22, Mat &res)
{         
   bool ret = false;
   // input size (-1 for the safe bilinear interpolation)
   const int width = im.cols-1;
   const int height = im.rows-1;
   // output size
   const int halfWidth  = res.cols >> 1;
   const int halfHeight = res.rows >> 1;
   float *out = res.ptr<float>(0);
   const float *imptr  = im.ptr<float>(0);
   for (int j=-halfHeight; j<=halfHeight; ++j)
   {
      const float rx = ofsx + j * a12;
      const float ry = ofsy + j * a22;
      #pragma omp simd
      for(int i=-halfWidth; i<=halfWidth; ++i, out++)
      {
         float wx = rx + i * a11;
         float wy = ry + i * a21;
         const int x = (int) floor(wx);
         const int y = (int) floor(wy);
         if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height)
         {
            // compute weights
            wx -= x; wy -= y;
            int rowOffset = y*im.cols;
            int rowOffset1 = (y+1)*im.cols;
            // bilinear interpolation
            *out =
                (1.0f - wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * imptr[rowOffset+x]   + wx * imptr[rowOffset+x+1]) +
                (       wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * imptr[rowOffset1+x] + wx * imptr[rowOffset1+x+1]);
         } else {
            *out = 0;
            ret =  true; // touching boundary of the input            
         }
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

As suggested by Intel Advisor, I added `#pragma omp simd` to force vectorization since the compiler (`icpc` 2017 update 3) assumed an inexistent dependency. On my AVX2 machine this doesn't produce any error and actually improve perfomance.

However, on the AVX-512 machine (with same compiler and version) this generates a segmentation fault. Why this happens?

The compilation flags are the same, expect that one use `-xCORE-AVX2` and the other one `-xMIC-AVX512`. This is the complete set of compilation flags:

```
INTEL_OPT=-O3 -ipo -simd -xCORE-AVX2 -parallel -qopenmp -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -fma -align -finline-functions
INTEL_PROFILE=-g -qopt-report=5 -Bdynamic -shared-intel -debug inline-debug-info -qopenmp-link dynamic -parallel-source-info=2 -ldl
```

Comment: That code looks oddly familiar ;) Could the Segmentation Fault be on the last few elements? AVX-512 obviously uses 256 bits more than AVX-256, and if your input size is an odd multiple of 256 bits (32 bytes) then you might read past the end of a page with 512 bits at a time.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for your comment, I'm glad that you remember lol. I don't understand what you mean by "input size", but if you mean the number of cycles in the vectorized `for`, then it's highly unstable. Some `halfWidth` examples are 20, 9, 17... while `halfHeight` values are 48, 20, 9, 43...  If you mean the `im` size some examples of `width` are 1368, 683, 62 ... while `height` 50, 1061, 58, ...

Comment: @MSalters what I mean is that if it was a multiple problem, with these values should have happened for AVX2 too, don't you think? Besides, I thought that `omp simd` was taking care of creating reminder and peeling loops

Comment: @MSalters notice that the values that I reported are not the correspondent to each other, I just reported random number that I've seen from their printing.

Comment: @MSalters can you help me on this?

Comment: No experience with AVX-512 I'm afraid, and that seems to be the crucial difference here.

Comment: Where does the segmentation fault happen? (Compile it with `-g` and run under `gdb`). Also you can try to analyze it with `valgrind`.

Comment: In `            *out =
                (1.0f - wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * imptr[rowOffset+x]   + wx * imptr[rowOffset+x+1]) +
                (       wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * imptr[rowOffset1+x] + wx * imptr[rowOffset1+x+1]);`